# How to fix "could not be scrolled into view" error In Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm using Selenium to automate an application but when I tried to click on an `<a>` tag, It throws below error:

> Element `<a id="play_button" class="clickable myButton margin_t15
>   lang_57 medium_font" href="javascript:;">` could not be scrolled into
>   view.

I'm using Selenium with C# and Firefox V62!

Also, I know that the element is hidden, and it will appear 5 seconds after loading the web page! Now how can I fix this error?

I also tried `by.xpath(), by.name()` and too many methods like these!

Here is my code:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Url = "The Web Site";
driver.FindElement(By.Id("play_button")).Click();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to fix the problem:

```
IJavascriptExecutor js = (IJavascriptExecutor) driver;
button = river.FindElement(By.Id("play_button"));
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", button);
button.Click()
```

PS: You can also use explicit wait to be clickable the element and after that click on it.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: this solution did not work for me. what worked is:
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('play_button').click();")